# What is the most efficient way to connect 20 Lamps for my backyard?

Tags: wiring

So as the title says, I have bought 100 feet wire, 20 lamps and 20 lamp holders.

Each lamp is 110v and 3w, and my electrical source is 110v. I can't remember anything from electricity courses except that there is a serious and a parallel way of connecting to an electrical source.

What is my best approach here and how should I wire them? Taking into consideration that they should look nice. Diagrams are best!

Comment: Wire them in parallel, seriously.

Comment: @Transistor Seriously, will they look nice? parallel = too many wires no?

Comment: @SandraK No. Why should you get many cables? Basically, imagine extension cords with two outlets at the end: one to plug in the next lamp with a short cable, and one to plug in the next extension cord...

Comment: @MarcusMüller hmm, can you please draw it for me?

Comment: @SandraK exactly as in Transistor's answer.

Comment: @Transistor Shirley you can't be series...

Comment: The job must also be done safely and correctly (and neatly, per Electrical Code 110.12). For that we need more info.  How will the !ights be physically mounted? To a building?  Posts? Along a fence? Festoons (overhead rope)? What type of cable did you buy? How long will this be in use?

Answer (score 2):

> ... there is a serious and a parallel way of connecting to an electrical source. - Sandra.

---

> Wire them in parallel, seriously. – Transistor.

I was being a little naughty with my comment. You meant "*series* and a parallel way", not "serious". I couldn't resist.

If they are 110 V lamps and you have a 110 V supply then they have to be wired in parallel. That means you need a cable with live, neutral and, if the lamps require it, an earth. The cable can loop from fitting to fitting so that they appear to be daisy chained but the wiring is in parallel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAq2h3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Daisy-chained parallel lamp wiring.*